# What kind of infinitive is it in “to come home to be killed”?

Tags: terminology, infinitives

In this example:

> Agamemnon comes home to be killed by his wife and her lover.

We are quite sure that he didn't plan on dying, so *comes home to be killed* is not the “infinitive of purpose”. What is it then? Is there a grammatical term for that?

---

Edited, another example:

> She came home to pick her car.

Here,  *to pick* is the “infinitive of purpose”.  In contrast:

> She came home to find the house has burned to the ground.

Here, though, *to find* is ***not*** the “infinitive of purpose”, so what kind of infinitive is it?

Comment: He didn't plan on it, but someone might have done.  e.g. Fate, or the Author.  Just throwing it out there...

Answer (score 2):

I have seen this called an *infinitive of result*. That strikes me as a happy term: you could then think of the other uses as subsets:

- The *infinitive of purpose* is an *infinitive of **sought*** (or ***desired***) *result*.
- Your house-burned-to-the-ground example is an *infinitive of **unexpected** result*.
- Your Agamemnon example is an *infinitive of **unsought***  ( or ***ironic***) *result*.

Comment: There's certainly irony in the Agamemnon example (home being safety from the wars); 'only to be' is often used here. The house-burned-to-the-ground / leaking-pipe / a-check-for-$10 000 / her-dog-had-chewed-up-her-slippers ... type is an unexpected eventuality (result at least strongly suggests consequence).

Answer (score 0):

I see a passive infinitive there, *to be killed.* As the action is not performed by Agamemnon himself, it doesn't necessarily have to be his choice.

Answer (score -1):

It could be improved with a comma:

> Agamemnon comes home [after surviving the battle], [only] to be killed
>   by his wife and her lover.